System Verilog assertion to verify that one signal is 2 clock cycle delayed version of the other
I have 2 inputs to my module, namely sig_1 and sig_2(both multi-bit). I want to check using assertions that whether sig_2 is a 2 clock cycle delayed version of sig_1, whenever sig1_1 changes.
i tried the below logic:
property delay_verif;
@(sig_1)
@(posedge clk)
(sig_1 |-\> ##2 (sig_2 == sig_1);
endproperty
Assertion1: assert property(delay_verif)
$display("value match successful at time: %t", $time);
else $display("value not matches at time: %t",$time);

but it does not work

Use only one event @(posedge clk)
property delay_verif;
@(posedge clk)
$changed(sig_1) |-> ##2 sig_2 == $past(sig_1,2);
endproperty
Assertion1: assert property(delay_verif)
  $info("value match successful at time: %t", $time);
  else $error("value not matches at time: %t",$time);

Note that this allows sig_2 to change when sig_1 does not change. You might want this instead.
property delay_verif;
    @(posedge clk)
    always ##2 sig_2 == $past(sig_1,2);
endproperty


Thanks, thus helps a lot! But is there a way we can use the above logic to check for n-cycle delay between signals(as in a general case)?? If not in this case, any way to have a general n-cycle delay between signals check?

N must be a constant in a property.  If N is a variable, you must use local variables and a counter. https://verificationacademy.com/forums/t/usage-of-variable-in-delay-for-sva/33254
